How to disable wrapping in PyCharm debug console
I'm trying to disable line wrapping in the debug console so I make it easier to read matrices and things. I see the option for soft wrapping but this isn't what I'm looking for. Seems like there's a specified width somewhere which cuts it to the next line and I can't find an option for increasing/disabling that.

